# Plotting a plot until it hits another plot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-4,xmax=4,
            ymin=-15,ymax=15,
            height = 5in,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style=->, xlabel = {$x_1$}, ylabel={$x_2$},
            %axis equal,
            legend cell align = {left},
            every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},          anchor=west,},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},           anchor=south,}, 
            title= {Extremal Curves Problem 1},         title style={xshift=0, yshift=1.75em},
            domain=0:15,samples=300,legend pos=outer north east]
            \addplot[latex-][color = blue, thick, domain = 2:3] {-1 + (x + 1)^2};
            \addplot[latex-][color = blue, thick, domain = 1:2] {-1 + (x + 1)^2} node[below right, pos = 0.5, font = \small] {\(u^* = 1\)};
            \addplot[color = blue, thick, domain = 0:1] {-1 + (x + 1)^2};
            \addplot[-latex][color = red, thick, domain = -3:-2] {1 - (-x + 1)^2};
            \addplot[-latex][color = red, thick, domain = -2:-1] {1 - (-x + 1)^2} node[above left, pos = 0.5, font = \small] {\(u^* = -1\)};
            \addplot[color = red, thick, domain = -1:0] {1 - (-x + 1)^2};
            \addplot [color = red, thick, dashed, domain = 0:3, -latex] ({-1 + (4 + 1)*exp(-x)}, {-1 + (-15 + 1)*exp(-2*x)});
            \addplot [color = blue, thick, dashed, domain = 0:3, -latex] ({1 + (-4 - 1)*exp(-x)}, {1 + (15 - 1)*exp(-2*x)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{Extremal curves for problem 1. Note that the red curve is the fastest curve.}
\end{figure}
```

And here is the corresponding output:

[image]

Edit:
I would like to make some plots like the dashed plots such that the blue dashed plot stops on the blue solid one, and the red dashed plot on the red solid plot, with a couple of arrows spaced evenly in each of those plots. The criteria is that the dashed plots appearing above the solid curve will be blue (e.g. plot starting from (-4, -2) will be blue and will go to the blue solid curve), while the dashed plots appearing below the solid curve will be red (e.g. plot starting from (4, 2) will be red and will go to the red solid curve). Is there a way of doing so in `pgfplots`? I tried the `\clip` command, but it only clips off one part of it instead of all of it. Is there a way to solve the problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can add arrows with the `decorations.markings` library, and stop one path at another path with the pgfplots library `fillbetween`. This allows you to access intersection segments of intersecting paths. Unfortunately, it seems that one cannot find the intersection segments of decorated paths easily, which is why I add the path used for the intersection segments separately. The benefit is that the path used for the intersection combines the blue and red curves.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{arrow marks/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
 mark=between positions #1 and 1 step #1 with {\arrow{>}}}},
 arrow marks/.default=10pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=4,
        ymin=-15,ymax=15,
        height = 5in,width=0.9\textwidth,
        axis lines=center,
        axis line style=->, xlabel = {$x_1$}, ylabel={$x_2$},
        %axis equal,
        legend cell align = {left},
        every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},          anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},           anchor=south,}, 
        title= {Extremal Curves Problem 1},         title style={xshift=0, yshift=1.75em},
        domain=0:15,samples=300,legend pos=outer north east]
        \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,color = blue, thick, domain = 3:0,
        tips=proper] 
        {-1 + (x + 1)^2};
        \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,tips=proper,
        color=red,thick, domain = -3:0] {1 - (-x + 1)^2};
        \addplot[draw=none,name path=second, domain = -3:3]
         {-sign(x)*(1 - (abs(x) + 1)^2)};
        \addplot[draw=none,name path=first,domain=0:3] 
        ({-1 + (2 + 1)*exp(-x)}, {-1 + (2 + 1)*exp(-2*x)});
        \draw [->,>=latex,orange,thick,arrow marks=1cm,
        intersection segments={of=first and second, sequence={A0},}];
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Extremal curves for problem 1. Note that the red curve is the fastest
curve.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is also possible to use `\clip` to top a path.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{arrow marks/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
 mark=between positions #1 and 1 step #1 with {\arrow{>}}}},
 arrow marks/.default=10pt}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=4,
        ymin=-15,ymax=15,
        height = 5in,width=0.9\textwidth,
        axis lines=center,
        axis line style=->, xlabel = {$x_1$}, ylabel={$x_2$},
        %axis equal,
        legend cell align = {left},
        every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},          anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},           anchor=south,}, 
        title= {Extremal Curves Problem 1},         title style={xshift=0, yshift=1.75em},
        domain=0:15,samples=300,legend pos=outer north east]
        \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,color = blue, thick, domain = 3:0,
            tips=proper] 
        {-1 + (x + 1)^2};
        \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,tips=proper,
            color=red,thick, domain = -3:0] {1 - (-x + 1)^2};
        \clip plot[variable=\x,domain=-3:3] 
        (\x,{-sign(\x)*(1 - pow(abs(\x) + 1,2))}) |-cycle;
        \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks=1cm,tips=proper,
            color=orange,thick,domain=0:3] 
        ({-1 + (2 + 1)*exp(-x)}, {-1 + (2 + 1)*exp(-2*x)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Extremal curves for problem 1. Note that the red curve is the fastest
curve.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also set the arrows at certain fractions of the length of the plot.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.16}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{arrow marks/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,
 mark=between positions 1/#1 and 1-1/#1 step 1/#1 with {\arrow{>}}}},
 arrow marks/.default=5}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[tips=proper]
    \begin{axis}[
        xmin=-4,xmax=4,
        ymin=-15,ymax=15,
        height = 5in,width=0.9\textwidth,
        axis lines=center,
        axis line style=->, xlabel = {$x_1$}, ylabel={$x_2$},
        %axis equal,
        legend cell align = {left},
        every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},          anchor=west,},
        every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},           anchor=south,}, 
        title= {Extremal Curves Problem 1},         title style={xshift=0, yshift=1.75em},
        domain=0:15,samples=300,legend pos=outer north east]
        \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks,color = blue, thick, domain = 3:0] 
        {-1 + (x + 1)^2};
        \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks,
            color=red,thick, domain = -3:0] {1 - (-x + 1)^2};
        \clip plot[variable=\x,domain=-3:3] 
        (\x,{-sign(\x)*(1 - pow(abs(\x) + 1,2))}) |-cycle;
        \addplot[->,>=latex,arrow marks,
            color=orange,thick,domain=0:3] 
        ({-1 + (2 + 1)*exp(-x)}, {-1 + (2 + 1)*exp(-2*x)});
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\caption{Extremal curves for problem 1. Note that the red curve is the fastest
curve.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you mind posting some code in which `\clip’ is being used? Also, why is there an arrow tip pointing upward at the origin?

Comment: @Superman I added the clip option, too. There was a stray arrow because I forgot to add `tips=proper` on that plot, I only had it in the other one.

Comment: In the line `\clip plot[variable=\x,domain=-3:3] (\x,{-sign(\x)*(1 - pow(abs(\x) + 1,2))}) |-cycle;' the portion `\clip plot[variable=\x,domain=-3:3] (\x,{-sign(\x)*(1 - pow(abs(\x) + 1,2))})' clips any incoming plots, but what does the `|-cycle` do?

Comment: @Superman It closes the path via a rectangular corner. That is from the last point it goes down vertically to the same vertical position as the starting point and then closes the path.

Comment: I think I didn’t make my question clear. I know that the `|-` is some intersection command (or position referencing command), but what about the term `cycle`? I just want to know its meaning in the context in general (and for this plot in this case)

Comment: @Superman My previous comment answers precisely this question.

Comment: Aaahhhh, so sorry, it just clicked. The term `cycle` just forms a loop!

Comment: By the way, I just copied your `\clip` code (the second one) into Texpad, but the orange plot isn’t appearing. What could be the problem?

Comment: @Superman I do not know. The codes work on an updated TeXLive installation.

Comment: I figured out why: Texpad on my iPad used the default compatibility settings, and my latex compiler (TexpadTex) does not support pgfplots beyond 1.16. I had to change it to pdflatex to make it work.

Comment: I realized that it can only work on one side of the plot; can you do it such that if I were to plot something coming from the left, it hits the blue curve? For some reason, the part that is supposed to be shown is cut off, while the part that is cut off is actually showing up given your code for the second plot.

Comment: I just edited the question for you to look at. Do you know how to tackle it? I need to turn in my homework with this plot by 5 PM PST

Comment: @Superman Sorry to disappoint you. The comments section under a post is not a TeX hot line. I have answered this question. Since you do not seem to agree (otherwise you had accepted my answers or at least upvoted), I think it is time to move on. To be clear, I do believe that I did answer the (original) question thoroughly and went far beyond what's usual when answering all these follow-up question.

Comment: I deeply apologize, I think I didn’t formulate my original question properly, as I didn’t put in all my needs in this question. Let me make up another question following this

Comment: @Superman, the question here is not, if your "real" question is answered, but if your *actually asked* question was answered. This seems to be the case here so you should accept the answer.And there is absolutely no problem to ask another/follow-up question if you notice that you have more/another questions as you did.

Comment: Actually, that answer didn’t work when I tried that out earlier; it didn’t give me the desired result for other cases.