# Plotting plots to stop on solid curve from both sides

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

This is a follow up question to [Plotting a plot until it hits another plot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/538108/plotting-a-plot-until-it-hits-another-plot); I edited it in the previous post, but I decided to make a new one as per someone’s suggestion.

Here is the code:

```
\begin{figure}[H]\centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \begin{axis}[
            xmin=-4,xmax=4,
            ymin=-15,ymax=15,
            height = 5in,
            axis lines=center,
            axis line style=->, xlabel = {$x_1$}, ylabel={$x_2$},
            %axis equal,
            legend cell align = {left},
            every axis x label/.style={ at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},          anchor=west,},
            every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:1.05)},           anchor=south,}, 
            title= {Extremal Curves Problem 1},         title style={xshift=0, yshift=1.75em},
            domain=0:15,samples=300,legend pos=outer north east]
            \addplot[latex-][color = blue, thick, domain = 2:3] {-1 + (x + 1)^2};
            \addplot[latex-][color = blue, thick, domain = 1:2] {-1 + (x + 1)^2} node[below right, pos = 0.5, font = \small] {\(u^* = 1\)};
            \addplot[color = blue, thick, domain = 0:1] {-1 + (x + 1)^2};
            \addplot[-latex][color = red, thick, domain = -3:-2] {1 - (-x + 1)^2};
            \addplot[-latex][color = red, thick, domain = -2:-1] {1 - (-x + 1)^2} node[above left, pos = 0.5, font = \small] {\(u^* = -1\)};
            \addplot[color = red, thick, domain = -1:0] {1 - (-x + 1)^2};
            \addplot [color = red, thick, dashed, domain = 0:3, -latex] ({-1 + (4 + 1)*exp(-x)}, {-1 + (-15 + 1)*exp(-2*x)});
            \addplot [color = blue, thick, dashed, domain = 0:3, -latex] ({1 + (-4 - 1)*exp(-x)}, {1 + (15 - 1)*exp(-2*x)});
        \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture} 
    \caption{Extremal curves for problem 1. Note that the red curve is the fastest curve.}
\end{figure}
```

And here is the corresponding output:

[image]

I would like to make some plots like the dashed plots such that the blue dashed plot stops on the blue solid one, and the red dashed plot on the red solid plot, with a couple of arrows spaced evenly in each of those plots. The criteria is that the dashed plots appearing above the solid curve will be blue (e.g. plot starting from (-4, -2) will be blue and will go and stop the blue solid curve), while the dashed plots appearing below the solid curve will be red (e.g. plot starting from (4, 2) will be red and will go and stop at the red solid curve). Is there a way of doing so in `pgfplots`? I tried the `\clip` command, but it only clips off one side of the plot of it instead of actually clipping off the dashed plots coming from both sides. Is there a way to solve the problem such that only the dashed plots will stop/get clipped once they hit the solid curve?

Edit: here is what I meant: From the book Optimal Control Theory by Donald Kirk: [image]

What it would be like if drawn on LaTeX:

[image]

What I am actually trying to draw:

[image]

Basically, the blue and red solid curve is called the “switching curve”, and the ones not on the switching curve are shown approaching it, then stopping there. Those ones are supposed to be the dashed ones that I am drawing.

I hope that if somebody answers, the problem will be fully solved. Thank you!

Comment: If the previous question was solved, would you mind accepting the answer?

Comment: Sorry for responding this so late, but I should have accepted the answer to this question, not the previous one, because I ran into a similar problem for a more complicated plot.

Comment: You can accept one answer of every question, if that -- as I stated in the comment in the answer of the other question -- answered the actually **asked** question. You have to blame **yourself** if you didn't ask the *right* question but not  us, the helper. I guess that not may of us are visionaries. Also there was a downvote to the (in the meantime deleted) answer of *this* question. I hope that was not you because in its last state it seems to have answered your question. So I voted to undelete it ...

Comment: Ok, sorry for not responding to earlier message on time, I was super busy on other homework, so I forgot about accepting this answer.

Comment: You *have* found the time to answer to my comment, but didn't have time to accept the answer of your previous question, so I guess *we* (the helpers) also don't have time to answer your question ...

Comment: Actually, that downvote was from me, but I forgot to upvote it when he modified the solution... sorry for not being so responsive on time...